# Expected Name found { ; tring to find objects with specific field value

Tags: express, graph, graphql

I'm trying to get familiar with graphql. So I have an entity called `Car` in BE. And I have only `Cars` exposed.

Now I'm trying to find all the cars from `Cars`, where year(launch) is certain say 2001. It's actually a variable. Now I think the following query should work.

```
query GetCars($y: String!) {
      cars({ year: $y }) {
        id
        year
    }
}
```

But it gives me error saying, **`Expected Name found {`**, it throws the error at the second dollar sign.

`filters` and `where` is also undefined.

Can anyone give me some hint to resolve this problem?

Using: **GraphiQL**

Answer (score 0):

In `cars({ year: $y})` the name of your argument is missing - arguments always need to have a name in GraphQL and the name of your arguments and their GraphQL type are defined in your schema.

Assuming your `cars` fields has an argument called `year` in your schema, you need to rewrite your query to: `cars(year: $y)`.
Assuming your `cars` fields has a `filter` or something like that defined in the schema and that `filter` expects an `input` object type that has - maybe among others - a field `year`,  you would write: `cars(filter: { year: $y })`.